# How to turn point sources/stars from an image into NaNs?

Tags: python, nan, astronomy, dithering

I have been trying to figure out a way to change point sources/stars into NaNs, with each star covering a different amount of pixels. I have 9 of these images (dithered) that all needs to go through this process (also, I can't use cv2). I have the x and y pixel coordinates of each star, generated by Source Extractor.

I tried turning all pixels above a certain value in NaNs, which didn't work since the background sometimes exceeded the value of dim stars in other regions. This is my code, where dse is the Source Extractor output for each image:

```
# get the x and y pixel coordinates of each source extractor output
xcoord = []
ycoord=[]
E=[]
for k in dse:
    x = k['X_IMAGE']
    y = k['Y_IMAGE']
    e = k['FWHM_IMAGE']
    xcoord.append(x)
    ycoord.append(y)
    E.append(e)

# plot each source detected by SExtractor and check them manually
n = 0
plt.imshow(dcals[n], cmap = 'gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.plot(xcoord[n], ycoord[n], ".", markersize=1)
plt.show()

# adjust each markersize to fit the size of each star
msize=[]
for i in range(8):
    markersize = (E[i]/0.608)*2
    msize.append(markersize)

# check each image manually
i=0
plt.imshow(dcals[i], cmap = 'gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.scatter(xcoord[i], ycoord[i], s=msize[i], c = 'blue', marker = '.')
plt.show()
```

Comment: is that [tag:python]?

Comment: @BagusTesa Yes, my code is in python

Comment: *"I tried turning all pixels above a certain value in `NaN`s, which didn't work since the background sometimes exceeded the value of dim stars in other regions."* - perhaps what you need is a mask as preprocessing, like high pass filter maybe? so that dim stars will stand out more compared to its surrounding. also, tag it with [tag:python] if it is.

Comment: The advice by @Bagus Tesa is definitely good! Probably you have to add a MRE (with data) to get more specific help with your case.

Comment: Kindly click [edit] and add representative images and also a proper [mcve] that is ***complete***.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.